# LOOKUPVALUE + SUM Q

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-embedded

I would like sum in a lookupvalue.  Is that possible or is there another command(s) that I need to look at to achieve my desired outcome?

I have a budget table with a field and would like to scan a transaction table with the same field name.  How do I sum all the transactions and put the total into the budget table?

[image]

I am wanting to sum the transactions to the corresponding field(s) in the Budget Table.

Comment: Can you give some example input and expected output? That would make this much easier to answer.

Comment: you will need to do some data modeling first - to create a star schema. Column "_link" should be split into 3 columns (For example, Date, Region, Country), in both tables. Then you need to add calendar table to your model, and connect it to column "date" in both tables. Then create another table for Location (Country, Region), and connect it to transaction and budget table. Once this is done, you will be able to summarize and align amounts in both tables.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first time answering to StackOverflow and I hope I get this right.

From my understanding, you want to sum the `_amt` value from the Transaction Table into the Budget Table in Power BI using Dax. In the Budget Table, what you can do is the following:

```
Sum_amt_2018 = CALCULATE(SUM('Transaction Table'[_amt]),FILTER('Transaction Table', 'Transaction Table'[_link] = 'Budget Table'[_link]))
```

Hope this helps.